# Openwrt two nic on the same vlan instead of alias?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openwrt, interface

I have a TP-Link WR1043ND with 1 wan and 1 lan cables attached. The lan cable currently have 2 ips of two different network, using an alias. The two networks share the same switch.

I'd  like the router to forward between the two.
Currently the routers sends ICMP redirect to the first network telling the clients to go to the second network directly, which is impossible.

Could I create a second virtual nic in the same vlan and assign it the IP on the second network?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLAN works using the GUI. [image]

I created a nic using VLAN 3 with the IP I wanted for the second network.

Since linux supports STP only for bridging I needed dedicated wires for the second nic.
Plugging the second nic in the same switch as the LAN made the network going down.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to OpenWRT but works with any Linux 2.6 - based distro. Just disable the sending of ICMP redirects for your aliased interface (assumed eth0 for the code examples):

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/send_redirects
```

which would be effective until re-setting or reboot. To make the setting permanent add this line to */etc/sysctl.conf*:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects = 0
```

and run `sysctl -p` to reload the configuration.

Comment: yes, that could do it, but I'd like to have 2 nic with 1 ip each :)

Comment: @Sirber in this case the simplest, most secure and best-documented way would be to use a VLAN-capable switch and tagged interfaces.

Comment: I agree, but the main question is about a TP-Link WR1043ND and OpenWRT :) http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr1043nd?s[]=1043nd#specific.configuration

Comment: @Sirber is there anything in this constellation that would prevent you from using VLANs? OpenWRT does support them, the employed RTL8366RB chip does support them and you should use them - unless you *really* are willing to go the troubled road of [macvlan-interfaces](http://www.candelatech.com/~greear/vlan.html) or [veth-interfaces](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/packages/net/veth). Don't do it. You have been warned.

Comment: I tryed VLAN but I plugged it in the same switch. Linux does not support STP so the whole network went down. I installed dedicated wires and it works perfectly now.